# How to merge two pfd files using pypdf2, when one of the files is chosen from a popup window using tkinter

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, pypdf

In this first section of code I choose a file from the popup window using tkinter:

```
# GUI.py
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter as tk
# Create the window and hide it
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Now you are free to popup any dialog that you need
filetypes = (("PDF file", "*.pdf"), ("All files", "*.*"))
filepath = askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)

# Now use the filepath
import re
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple

lines = []

with pdfplumber.open(filepath) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
#        print(text)

# Destroy the window
root.destroy()
```

In this section I merge two selected pdf files together.
**I would want to change the code so that the first pdf file (pdf1File) would be the file selected at the beginning from the popup window using tkinter**, while the second (pdf2File) would stay the same. How can I do that?

```
import PyPDF2 
 
# Open the files that have to be merged one by one
pdf1File = open('Fraction_Event_Report.pdf', 'rb')
pdf2File = open('Summary_output.pdf', 'rb')
 
# Read the files that you have opened
pdf1Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf1File)
pdf2Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf2File)
 
# Create a new PdfFileWriter object which represents a blank PDF document
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

# Loop through all the pagenumbers for the first document
for pageNum in range(pdf1Reader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdf1Reader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
 
# Loop through all the pagenumbers for the second document
for pageNum in range(pdf2Reader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdf2Reader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
 
# Now that you have copied all the pages in both the documents, write them into the a new document
pdfOutputFile = open('MergedFiles.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutputFile)
 
# Close all the files - Created as well as opened
pdfOutputFile.close()
pdf1File.close()
pdf2File.close()
```

Comment: What is confusing you about this?  Instead of hardcoding the first file name, you use the name in the `filepath` value you got from the dialog.

Comment: you're right. I figured it out. I had a syntax error. it worked. Thanks